# Angular 10 call finalize() when nested observables complete

Tags: angular, subscribe, rxjs-observables

finalize nested observables after the last item is processed. [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/map-example-jx43fg?file=index.ts)

finalize() should be called when the observables complete - all the numbers (11, 12, 13) are output.

How should the observables be nested?

```
import { from } from "rxjs";
import { map, finalize } from "rxjs/operators";

//emit (1,2,3)
const data = [
  {
    userId: 1,
    id: 1
  },
  {
    userId: 1,
    id: 2
  },
  {
    userId: 1,
    id: 3
  }
];
const source = from(data);
//add 10 to each value
const example = source.pipe(map(val => add(val.id)));
//output: 11,12,13
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
function add(n) {
  return n + 10;
}
```

The Stackblitz was a starting point.

In the following code, I want to send a message to all the users.

I want to unsubscribe and close the modal when all the messages are sent.

```
  submit() {
    const users = from(this.form.value.users).pipe(
      finalize(() => {
        console.log('finalize'),
        this.dismissModal()
      }),
      map(user => this.buildMessage(user))
    ).subscribe(message => {
      this.subscription = this.firestoreService.addMessage(message)
        .subscribe();
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription?.unsubscribe();
  }

  dismissModal() {
    this.dialogRef.close('modal dismissed');
  }
```

Now `firestoreService.addMessage(message)` logs the `console.log('addMessage')` and returns but does not add the message to the database.

```
  addMessage(data:Message):Observable<T> {
    console.log('addMessage');
    data.timestamp = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
    return this.authService.currentUser$.pipe(
      switchMap(user => {
        console.log('addMessage user: ', user);
        if (user) {
          return this.firestore
            .collection<any>(user.company)
            .doc(user.licence)
            .collection<any>(message)
            .add(data)
              .then(res => {
                console.log("Message successfully added! ", res);
              })
              .catch(e => {
                console.error("Error adding message: ", e);
              });
          } else {
            return [];
          }
        }
      )
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hi, it isn't clear when you talk about multiples observables or nested observables, in your example, i just see one observable from an array data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use higher order operators in this case **switchMap**

With switchMap you subscribe `buildMessage(user)` and pass it observable result to `firestoreService.addMessage(message)` in only one pipe operations.

```js
submit() {
  this.subscription = from(this.form.value.users).pipe(
    finalize(() => {
      console.log('finalize'),
      this.dismissModal()
    }),
    map(user => this.buildMessage(user)),
    switchMap((message) => this.firestoreService.addMessage(message))
  ).subscribe();
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.subscription?.unsubscribe();
}

dismissModal() {
  this.dialogRef.close('modal dismissed');
}
```

Edited

You need to return Observables in this way.
`from` create observable from promise
`of` create observable from values in sequence

```js
 addMessage(data:Message):Observable<T> {
    console.log('addMessage');
    data.timestamp = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
    return this.authService.currentUser$.pipe(
      switchMap(user => {
        console.log('addMessage user: ', user);
        if (user) {
          return from(this.firestore
            .collection<any>(user.company)
            .doc(user.licence)
            .collection<any>(message)
            .add(data))
          } else {
            return of([]);
          }
        }
      )
    );
  }
```

Comment: I edited my question. Now this.firestoreService.addMessage does not add a message to the database

Comment: I updated my answare.
If you have another question please create a new stackoverflow question.

Comment: new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64474177/add-message-to-firestore-with-observable-from-switchman